# Why do I have to add "overflow:hidden" to make the navigation bar visible on the page?

Tags: css

I'm a newbie to css and have been struggling with the following problem of my code for the whole morning. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me find out the reason.

***Why does the navigation bar totally disappear from the page if I don't set the "overflow" of "ul.navBar" to "hidden"?***

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    ul.navBar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #4277f4;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li:hover {
        background-color: #A2AEB3;
    }

    .dropDownContent {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #7DC9E3;
        width: 150px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
    .dropDownContent a {
        color: white;
        display: block;

    }
    .dropDownContent a:hover{
        background-color: #4A96B0;
    }


    li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
        display: block;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="navBar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropDownBtn"><a href="#">Products</a>
        <div class="dropDownContent">
            <a href="#">Product1</a>
            <a href="#">Product2</a>
            <a href="#">Product3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code page for this [navigation bar](https://jsfiddle.net/liutong_chen/njwemcck/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why does the navigation bar totally disappear from the page if I don't set the `overflow` of `ul.navBar` to `hidden`?

This is happening because the child elements of `.navBar` are being floated. Floated elements are taken out of the normal document flow and do not take up space. Because the children take up no space `.navBar` has no height .

Adding `overflow: hidden;` triggers a new block formatting context that prevents `.navBar` from *"collapsing"* when it has floated children.

---

Some people will suggest using `display: inline-block;`. Use with caution as each element will have white space around it that will make them larger than you think. Especially when using percentage widths.

Example:

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.inline li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gold;
}

.float li {
  float: left;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.flex {
  clear: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="inline">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="float">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Here's some options on [how to handle the white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) if you chose the `inline-block` route.

Answer (score 5):

Floated elements (your `li` in this case) have a height of 0. So, essentially, your `ul` element is 0 pixels tall.

Adding `display: inline-block` to your `li` elements allow for this to be corrected. Therefore, the `overflow` style for your `ul` is not required.

```css
ul.navBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #4277f4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: #A2AEB3;
}

.dropDownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #7DC9E3;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.dropDownContent a {
    color: white;
    display: block;

}
.dropDownContent a:hover{
    background-color: #4A96B0;
}


li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="navBar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropDownBtn"><a href="#">Products</a>
            <div class="dropDownContent">
                <a href="#">Product1</a>
                <a href="#">Product2</a>
                <a href="#">Product3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the white space around inline elements becomes an issue? How does one handle that?

Comment: @hungerstar Margin and padding should be all you need

Comment: IMHO that's a sloppy solution. Things become more complicated than they need to be at that point. It's a lot simpler to use `overflow: hidden;` or a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: @hungerstar Situation dictates

Comment: I'm not aware of a situation where one would chose to tackle the white space from inline elements with margin and padding when said white space is an issue. Please provide an example where margin/padding would preferred to using floats or flexbox. I'm honestly curious.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are floating your `li` elements which causes the `ul` to not have a height. Try using `display:inline-block;` instead.

```css
ul.navBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #4277f4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: #A2AEB3;
}

.dropDownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #7DC9E3;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.dropDownContent a {
    color: white;
    display: block;

}
.dropDownContent a:hover{
    background-color: #4A96B0;
}


li.dropDownBtn:hover .dropDownContent{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navBar">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropDownBtn"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <div class="dropDownContent">
        <a href="#">Product1</a>
        <a href="#">Product2</a>
        <a href="#">Product3</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: What if the white space around inline elements becomes an issue? How does one handle that?

Comment: [Here's a good article on that](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)