# This is an example seen in w3school on overflow: hidden used to show background color of a ul tag when the list is floated

Tags: css

This is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5)

I understand that the `overflow` property determines what to do with “the excess part” of something, for example, to hide or to put a scrollbar. In the example, if I erase the `overflow` property, the `ul` will be just a line as the list is floated.
How is the `overflow: hidden` is getting the `ul` back?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` is not getting the ul back here. The color of the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` are white because of which they are not visible. Also because of `float:"left"` on the `<li>`, the `background-color:"#333"` of the `<ul>` is not visible. All the css properties together are causing the effect.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand that the list items are not seen as the colour is white. I would like to understand-as the li element is floated, the ul container no longer has any content & it just becomes a line as the ht becomes 0, how does the overflow:hidden property undo's that that is how we are seeing the bg again.

Comment: Because of the floated elements. To understand it better visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007817/why-do-i-have-to-add-overflowhidden-to-make-the-navigation-bar-visible-on-the and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el

Comment: got it. Thank you.